# How to split string with quotes into array in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to split string with quotes into array in shell. e.g. I'd like split the following string

```
parameter_1 "parameter 2"
```

to

```
parameter_1
parameter 2
```

More examples:

```
param_1=value_1 param_2="value\"2"
```

to

```
param_1=value_1 
param_2="value\"2"
```

```
param_1=value_1 param_2="value*2"
```

to

```
param_1=value_1 
param_2="value*2"
```

BTW, the input string may also contain other special character, such as wildcard or quotes, I need a general argument parsing function.
It is easy to do that via command line library in java, but not sure how to do that in shell. Thanks

Comment: Can you use zsh instead of bash?

Comment: Where does this string come from? Is it in a variable? Does it contain shell meta characters?

Comment: @oguzismail it may contain wildcard or quotes, I just need a general shell solution to parsing arguments

Comment: @zjffdu: So you want to keep the first double quote, but remove the second one?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I have updated the example code

Comment: @zjffdu : Can the string have embedded newlines?

Comment: I would suggest updating the question with some more samples, including the mentioned special characters

Comment: I asked about `zsh` because in that shell it can be done with just `myarray=( ${(z)paramvar} )`, btw.

Comment: @Shawn. zsh won't work for me, because I am not sure whether user has zsh installed.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this bash script using a regex:

```bash
# input string
s='parameter_1 "parameter 2"'

# regex to match quoted OR non-space string
re='"[^"]*"|[^[:space:]]+'

# array to contain matches
arr=()

# start a loop to match our regex
# until string is non-empty
n=0
while [[ -n $s && $s =~ $re ]]; do
   m="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
   arr+=("$m")
   ((n+=${#m}))
   s="${s:$n}"
done

# check array content
declare -p arr
# or
echo
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a arr=([0]="parameter_1" [1]="\"parameter 2\"")

parameter_1
"parameter 2"
```

[Online Code Demo](https://ideone.com/hqI43r)

Comment: This would not work for me, because it is too specific, my input may also has other characters such as wildcard, I need a general solution to parse argument like any command line tool

Comment: @zjffdu: This would work with the solution posted. Did you try it? If you find a concrete example, where this solution fails, you have to post it.

Comment: Having wildcard in input is not at all an issue. However if you want to pass string as arguments to a script then a simple `for a; do echo "$a"; done` would also work. Or to put them in array use: `argsArr=( "$@" )`

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- double quotes (`"`) are used solely as delimiters
- there are no embedded newlines between pairs of double quotes

Guessing at what some other strings may look like, and dumping these into a file:

```
$ cat strings.dat
parameter_1 "parameter 2"
"parameter_3" "parameter 4"
 wild * card "and some ' quotes '"
```

One `awk` idea to break the data into non-empty fields:

```
awk -F'"' '                             # field delimiter = double quotes
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                   # loop through all fields
      { gsub(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/,"",$i)       # remove leading/trailing spaces
        if (length($i))                 # if field is not empty then ...
           print $i                     # print 
      }
}' strings.dat
```

This generates:

```
parameter_1
parameter 2
parameter_3
parameter 4
wild * card
and some ' quotes '
```

From here there are a few ways to read these into an array, one `mapfile` idea:

```
mapfile -t array < <(awk -F'"' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/,"",$i);if (length($i)) print $i}}' strings.dat)
```

Which generates:

```
$ typeset -p array
declare -a array=([0]="parameter_1" [1]="parameter 2" [2]="parameter_3" [3]="parameter 4" [4]="wild * card" [5]="and some ' quotes '")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- double quotes (`"`) are used solely as delimiters
- there are no embedded newlines between pairs of double quotes

Sticking solely with `bash`:

```
line='  parameter_1  "  parameter 2  "  '
val=
array=()

while [[ -n "${line}" ]]
do
    val="${line%%\"*}"                 # grab first "-delimited field
    line="${line#*\"}"                 # save rest of "-delimited fields

    val="${val##*( )}"                 # strip leading spaces
    val="${val%%*( )}"                 # strip trailing spaces
    line="${line##*( )}"               # edge case to strip spaces if this is all that is left in variable

    [[ -z "${val}" ]] && continue      # if empty then skip to next iteration of loop else ...

    array+=("${val}")                  # add to array
done
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p array
declare -a array=([0]="parameter_1" [1]="parameter 2")
```

---

---

An assortment of strings:

```
$ cat strings.dat
   parameter_1  "  parameter 2  "  
"parameter_3" "parameter 4"
 wild * card "and some ' quotes '"
```

Applying our code to this file of strings

```
while read -r line
do
    array=()
    
    while [[ -n "${line}" ]]
    do
        val="${line%%\"*}"                 # grab first "-delimited field
        line="${line#*\"}"                 # save rest of "-delimited fields
    
        val="${val##*( )}"                 # strip leading spaces
        val="${val%%*( )}"                 # strip trailing spaces
        line="${line##*( )}"               # edge case to strip spaces if this is all that is left in variable
    
        [[ -z "${val}" ]] && continue      # if empty then skip to next iteration of loop else ...
    
        array+=("${val}")                  # add to array
    done

    typeset -p array

done < strings.dat
```

This generates:

```
declare -a array=([0]="parameter_1" [1]="parameter 2")
declare -a array=([0]="parameter_3" [1]="parameter 4")
declare -a array=([0]="wild * card" [1]="and some ' quotes '")
```

Or if we want to load the entire file into a single array:

- move `array=()` before `while read -r line`
- move `typeset -p array` after `done < strings.dat`

This generates:

```
declare -a array=([0]="parameter_1" [1]="parameter 2" [2]="parameter_3" [3]="parameter 4" [4]="wild * card" [5]="and some ' quotes '")
```