# How to split quoted argument in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I am writing a shell script. The number of its argument is one, and the only argument is a doubly-quoted string containing spaces like this:

```sh
$ ./test.sh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"
```

(These are required specifications and cannot be changed.)

I want to get the following output for the above input.

```
a bcd   e
f ghi
jkl mn
```

However, I cannot get this result by using a simple `for` loop.

## In case of Bash

### shell script source

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for STR in $1; do
    echo $STR
done
```

### result

```sh
$ ./test.sh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"
'a
bcd
e'
'f
ghi'
'jkl
mn'
```

## In case of Zsh

### shell script source

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
for STR in $1; do
    echo $STR
done
```

### result

```sh
$ ./test.sh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"
'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'
```

How can I get the expected output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68539374/how-to-split-string-with-quotes-into-array-in-shell https://superuser.com/questions/1066455/how-to-split-a-string-with-quotes-like-command-arguments-in-bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434200/how-to-split-quoted-strings-in-bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233860/bash-splitting-line-with-quotes-into-parameters

Comment: I don't think you can expect the shell to contain a built-in parser for your ad-hoc and frankly rather strange requirements. Write a parser in portable POSIX `sh` (or use e.g. Awk or Python) and it will "magically" work in any Bourne-compatible shell.

Comment: Note that the `xargs` answer that was accepted is not perfect. In particular, it doesn't work with strings with newline literals within them.

Comment: Much cleaner awk solution that's portable across awk variants : …………………………………...
echo "${a}" | mawk getline RS='\47' | gcat -n  ………..
     1 a bcd   e…………..
     2 f ghi………………..
     3 jkl mn……………...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usiing `xargs` to split quoted arguments and run script itself again with split arguments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# If there is only one argument
if  [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
  # Use xargs to split arguments
  # and run itself with prepended dummy _ argument
  printf '%s' "$1" | xargs "$0" _
fi

# Remove/ignore prepend dummy argument
shift

i=0
for arg; do
  i=$((i + 1))
  printf 'Arg %d: %s\n' "$i" "$arg"
done
```

Output from the script with sample data:

```
$ sh a.sh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"
Arg 1: a bcd   e
Arg 2: f ghi
Arg 3: jkl mn
```

A very shortened version of the argument split and call self:

```sh
# Split quoted arguments and call self
[ "$2" ]||printf '%s' "$1"|xargs "$0" _;shift
# Process normal arguments as with any shell script
```

Comment: This is covered by existing duplicates, no?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The information about unquoting in Bash is very scattered and I may have contributed to scattering it more, sorry. The xarg thingy is in one place about processing lines from a file, and not in other places that describes parsing arguments. I choose to place it all in one here as it is both POSIX friendly and possibly more robust than `eval` or even `declare`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is with `awk` used with `'` as the field-separator and then empty fields are discarded outputting the non-empty fields (the separated arguments).

For example, you can do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awk -F "'" '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    match ($i, /[^[:blank:]]/)
    if (RSTART >0)
      print $i
  }
}' <<< $1
```

The `awk` script loops over each field separated by `'` and uses `match()` to check if a non-blank character is present. (`match()` sets `RSTART` to the 1's based index of the first non-blank, so testing if `RSTART > 0` tells you a non-blank is present)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash test.sh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"
a bcd   e
f ghi
jkl mn
```

If you like, you can use `mapfile -t` wrapping the `awk` command above in a *process substitution* to store the separate arguments in an array if you need to preserve them for later recall.

Since `awk` does not depend on which shell you have, this is portable to all shells (you would have to pipe the argument for those shells without *herestring* support.)

**Embedded Quotes Lose Meaning To The Shell**

I know you said you are stuck with providing the argument to your script in this manner. Know that is the wrong way to go. It is a [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) issue. The single-quotes within double-quotes lose any meaning as a special delimiting character and are simply treated as an embedded ASCII single-quote. This complicates using the command-line.

Forcing that command-line to work isn't a solution, it's *Work-Around*. The solution is to fix the way the arguments are being provided to your script.

Comment: Either [ mawk getline RS='\47' ] or [ gawk '!(NR%2)'  RS='\47' ] more than suffices to do the job

Comment: Yes, that is an option too or `\x27` if I recall correctly. Good point.

Comment: oh yea apologize for that notation - i'm overly octal-oriented myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash regular expression :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string=$1
pattern="[^']*'([^']+)'"

while [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]; do
    echo "Current argument : ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    string=${string:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
done
```

Run with :

```
./test.sh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"
```

Comment: Assuming that the OP wants quoting behavior equivalent to the shell's, this doesn't handle anything close to the full set of cases. For example, `"hello world"\ goodbye' world'` is all one string in shell (`hello world goodbye world`), switching quoting types partway through.

Answer (score -1):

Version for `zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
for str in ${(M)${(ps"'")argv}:#*[! ]*}; do
    print $str
done
```

This uses `zsh` expansions to split the input into an array on `'`, and then remove any members of the array that contain only spaces.

```
./test.zsh "'a bcd   e' 'f ghi' 'jkl mn'"  " '  leading space'"
a bcd   e
f ghi
jkl mn
  leading space
```